# Proving Rational Quotient Rule

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, fractions

How do I prove $\cfrac{x^m}{x^n}=x^{m-n}$ for $x>0$ and $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $m>n$

For me, I started with defining exponentiation, 
$$x^r=\underbrace{x \times x \times \ ... \times x}_{\text{r times}}$$
And so I say $$\cfrac{\underbrace{x \times x \times \ ... \times x}_{\text{m times}}}{\underbrace{x \times x \times \ ... \times x}_{\text{n times}}}\implies x^{m-n}$$

I think this is clear because of the fact that equal products in the numerator and denominator will cancel each other out until there's nothing left to cancel out, hence $m-n$. But I'm not sure if this is a good or solid approach.

Even if this is all the explanation I need, are there any interesting methods to prove this?

Comment: It's not so easy. Firstly, prove it for $x>0$ and $m,n$ are rational numbers. After this use the following: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut

Comment: If $m, n\in \mathbb R$ then $x^r = \underbrace{x*x*..... *x}$ is not a valid definition.  That definition only works if $m, n\in \mathbb N$ and if $m > n$.

Comment: So you need a definition of $x^r; r \in \mathbb R$.  And how your proof will go will depend *entirely* on what your definition is.

Comment: Ah I see, I'll fix my mistake now

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are assuming that $x>0$, $n$ and $m$ are positive integers and $m \geq n$. What you want to prove is equivalent to $x^{m}=x^{n}x^{m-n}$. So this follows from the fact that $x^{i+j}=x^{i}x^{j}$ (with $i=n, j=m-n$).